# JDBC Resource Pool with Tomcat6 on Centos5.5 and utf8 problems

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jdbc, utf-8, character-encoding

First of all: excuse me about my english.
And, after that...

I've got a Tomcat6 server on Centos5.5, with JDBC Resource Pool configured.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/BD"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="user"
            password="pass"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/BD?autoReconnect=true&amp;useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            maxActive="30"
            maxIdle="50"
            maxWait="-1"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
/>
```

And I've coded a class to establish connection to that DataSource (named DAO);

```
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/BD");
        connexio = ds.getConnection();
        sentencia = connexio.createStatement();
```

And here you have the code that i'm using to throw the queries:

```
            DAO conn = new DAO();
            ResultSet SQLresults = conn.executeSQL(SQLQuery);

            while (SQLresults.next()) {
                String string1 = SQLresults.getString(2);
                String string2 = SQLresults.getString(3);
                String string2 = SQLresults.getString(4).replaceAll("[\n\r]", " ");
                String string3 = SQLresults.getString(5).replaceAll("[\n\r]", " ");
                String string4 = SQLresults.getString(6).replaceAll("[\n\r]", " ");
            }
```

My DDBB (MySQL) has UTF8 by default, and I created all my tables with the "default charset=utf8" to be sure about that.

And....

I get almost all with well-formed UTF8 character encoding, but sometimes I've got errors with some chars. I'm sure that the issue is between the mysql and tomcat (so in my servlets or in the JDBC connection), because I see some bad-formed chars after servlet writes them, but they are well-formed on the MySQL UTF8 prompt in my terminal.

For example, in the MySQL UTF8 terminal (Putty, iMac Terminal, Ubuntu and Debian terminal) I see that:

> LG Optimus 2X and Optimus Black priced at €499 by Amazon Germany, not yet available to buy

but my servlet write that:

> LG Optimus 2X and Optimus Black priced at â?¬499 by Amazon Germany, not yet available to buy

And "â?¬" should be a "€" when I decode it... but it isn't. It's bad-formed.

Other example chars, in my UTF8 terminals:

> David Trueba: “Leer novelas me llevó al guión”: Tweet RUBÉN DARÍO ÁLVARE...

Servlets:

> David Trueba: â??Leer novelas me llevÃ³ al guiÃ³nâ?: Tweet RUBÃ?N DARÃO ÃLVARE...

But "â??", "â?", "Ã?" should be “ ” É (after decoding them) but they are corrupted UTF8 chars and I don't know why because the 85% of UTF8 chars are perfectly decoded. You can see that with: ó Í Á because they are totally well-formed.

What do you think about it?. If it helps, I send that UTF8 text to Android Devices, and when there is a bad-formed UTF8 char, I see .

BTW I use this page to be sure about good UTF8 text:

http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode

And.... it confirms about the well-formed and bad-formed chars.

Ah!, and the servlets write text in the browser (no html statements, only text), but I've been doing some tests and if I convert it to an html page and put the bad-formed data in the body and force them to be utf8 with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

The results are the same.

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two (potential) problems. First, in your JDBC URL you have used an `useEncoding` parameter while this is not officially recognized by MySQL JDBC driver. It should have been called `useUnicode`.

Then the servlet response part. It uses by default the platform default character encoding which is not UTF-8 per se. You need to explicitly set the character encoding of the servlet response to UTF-8 as well *before* you write any character to it. Since you are not using JSP, you need to manually set the content type as well.

```
resposne.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
resposne.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Do this *before* the first call on `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

Noted should be that the meta tag as given in your question is **ignored** when the content is been transferred over HTTP. Instead, the HTTP response `Content-Type` header will be used to determine the content type and character encoding. You can determine the HTTP header with for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), in the *Net* panel.

[image]

Comment: I've tried it just now and doesn't work. Now it prints: David Trueba: Ã¢â‚¬Å“Leer novelas me llevÃƒÂ³ al guiÃƒÂ³nÃ¢â‚¬Â:  Tweet                                        RUBÃƒâ€°N DARÃƒÂO ÃƒÂLVARE... and ALL is bad-formed UTF8 char :S.

Comment: Then the data was not transferred as UTF-8 at all. I checked your JDBC URL once again and I see that you used `useEncoding` (which doesn't exist at all) instead of `useUnicode`. Fix it and retry.

Comment: My JDBC URL is now like you said but nothing :(. The same without the response.setCharacterEncoding trick. " " and É (in this example) are not seeing well-formet but ó Á Í yes.

Comment: Did you do *both*? Both needs to be done. Well, that would only mean that the data in the DB itself is actually corrupt. How did you insert the data? Anyway, I would suggest to get yourself through the linked article to see if the DB tables are indeed properly created.

Comment: About the DB tables.... i thought so, but I've checked all my tables... and most important. All my terminals are in UTF8 mode (only utf8), and there aren't any bad-formed chars.

Comment: OK, let's eliminate this step by step. Are you using Firefox? What is *View > Character Encoding* (auto-)set on? What does Firebug say about the `Content-Type` header of the response you retrieve?

Comment: If I set character encoding with "Unicode" I've got the same, almost all of the chars are well-formet but our example has the same results with the bad-formed :(. And Firebug hasn't any Content-type field :S. I tested it with response.setCharacterEncoding and without it. And the same.

Comment: Ah right, you're emitting it as plain text, not forwarding to some JSP file (which would in turn set the right header). Add `response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");` (and keep the `setCharacterEncoding()`!). Do this *before* calling the `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` as well.

Comment: Umm.... same results. And there isn't any Content-Type :s:S... so strange. EDIT: I didn't see your edit :p. Trying just now... let's see

Comment: I've tested it... and... same... :(. EDIT: and there isn't any content-type :S

Comment: Are you running the code you think you are running? Edit, recompile, redeploy, etc. Add `System.out.println("blah")` and read server logs to be sure.

Comment: ctrl+r in firefox doens't reload without the cache u.u'... xD. Now, i'm using porn's mode ( xD ) i'm really reloading the page and there are some changes. There is a Content-Type field (as we thought)... but although I set character encoding in my firefox to UTF-8... I can't see the UTF8. All are like this: AfganistÃ¡n... (afghanistan in spanish has a á in Afganistán).

Comment: If `á` is represented as `Ã¡` then it can mean 2 things: the data was *actually* inserted using ISO 8859-1 encoding OR the response is *actually* written with ISO 8859-1. You need to ensure that you call `setCharacterEncoding()` **before** you call `getWriter()`. Do you have filters in your webapp which may be accessing the response like that?

Comment: I've got the code like this: response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); and for write I do out.print(); And nops, i haven't got any filters :s. About 8859-1... how is it possible? All my server is in UTF-8 included MySQL. Putty (for example) is in UTF8 mode and seeing the suposed bad-formed chars like well-formed chars :S.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(stringfromdatabase)`. What do you see in logs? (assuming it's written and read as UTF-8 as well!). Another try to exclude one and other may be to hardcode it in your source file `out.print("Afghanistán");` (and save source file itself as UTF-8 as well!). What do you see in browser?

Comment: In our example: " David Trueba: â€œLeer novelas me llevÃ³ al guiÃ³nâ€�: " and if you copy&paste to the page that i wrote there you have the well-formed and bad-formed chars.

Comment: Then it can only be the transfer from DB to Java which fails. Your JDBC connection string however looks fine (assuming you used `useUnicode`).

Comment: Umm..... I've just done the test that you said with "Afganistán". And If I write: out.print("Afganistán") or I declare a byte[] b = "Afganistán".getBytes("UTF-8") and print it out.print(new String(b,"UTF-8")) , I get "Afganistán" correctly both of them... but DIRECTLY "Afganistán" without rare letters. EDIT: and yes, i used useUnicode=true. EDIT2: here you have the new jdbc url: url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/BD?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"

Comment: The problem is definitely in the JDBC part. I can think of 2 things which you could try: 1) try `characterEncoding=utf8` instead of `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in JDBC URL. 2) try replacing/upgrading the JDBC driver. Maybe the JDBC driver version which you're currently using mismatches the MySQL server version.

Comment: utf8 didn't work. Let's see changing jdbc (i'm downloading now). EDIT: changed the JDBC driver... and nothing :(...

Comment: What JDBC driver version? What MySQL version? What JDK version?

Comment: Back to JDK/JRE: Are you using GCJ? Replace by OpenJDK and retry. GCJ has so many odd bugs.

Comment: About JDBC version => 5.1.14 (latest)
About MySQL version => 5.0.77
About JDK => OpenJDK 1.6

Comment: I don't know anymore. At least the root cause of the problem is likely in the JDBC part where data is been retrieved from the DB. I would concentrate on that part alone. Setup some Java class with a `main()` method which does a simple `Class.forName()`, `DriverManager.getConnection()`, `System.out.println(resultSet.getString("foo"))` and so on. It allows for quick playing/testing with different urls, drivers, DB settings, environmental settings, etc. Once you got that to work, then port to the servlet (and let us know here what the real culprit was).

Comment: BalusC I confirm you that the issue is in jdbc... i've made a simple script en PHP (i don't know php... but i think that i'm going to learn it) and it returns PERFECTLY the text u.u'....